# How can i use a variable created within a view as an argument within an action result? (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Within my view i have a piece of JavaScript where i have declared a variable ' Fk '

```
<script>
     function test(clickedID) 
     {
          var Fk = clickedID;                        
     }
</script>
```

I want to be able to use 'Fk' within an action result by passing it as a parameter.
For example:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ReadFk(int Fk) //i would imagine id pass Fk to the ActionResult through the use of its paramaters..?
        {
            var dataFileFk = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/ForeignKeyValue.txt");

            var textFileDataFk = Fk + Environment.NewLine;

            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(dataFileFk, textFileDataFk);

            return View();
        }
```

Is there an easy way of doing this?
Thank you!

Comment: since ReadFk is an ActionResult, I assume you want to redirect the user? Or do you just want to call a server-side function from javascript?

Comment: I believe i may have mistakenly asked my question. What i would like to do is: I have created the variable 'Fk' within my view. Now i want to be able to read the value of 'Fk' into a text file using an ActionResult. Therefore i would need to access 'Fk' within my ActionResult. I have updated my question with the full view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:
Since you want to pass a variable from javascript to a controller action and you want to be redirected afterwards, you can use `window.location.replace(url)`

```
<script>
   function test(clickedID) 
   {
      var Fk = clickedID;  

      // this will redirect you to a controller action while sending data parameter
      window.location.replace("http://yoursite.com/ControllerName/WriteFK?data="+Fk);
   }
</script>
```

Then create an action that will receive the data and write that to the text file;

```
// remove HttpPost and change to ActionResult
public ActionResult WriteFK(string data)
{
   // variable data will contain the FK
   // write to text file here

   // return view
   return View();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this, although i have run into an issue. Do you not mean to say 'public ActionResult WriteFK(string data)' ? By having this of type string, i am unable to return the view.

Comment: @SeventhWarhawk oh, sorry I thought you don't want to redirect. Changing the WriteFK function to ActionResult won't work because AJAX doesn't understand what an ActionResult is.

Comment: @SeventhWarhawk let me change the answer to a redirect instead, this way we don't need to use ajax.

Comment: @SeventhWarhawk updated the answer, this will redirect you to another controller action while sending the FK value. Is this behaving as you've expected?

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you so so much man. Could not appreciate it enough!